# Removing varying text phrases through RegEx in a Python Data frame

Tags: python, regex

Basically, I want to remove the certain phrase patterns embedded in my text data:

1. Starts with an upper case letter and ends with an Em Dash "—"
2. Starts with an Em Dash "—" and ends with a "Read Next"

Say, I've got the following data:

> CEBU CITY—The widow of slain human rights lawyer ....  citing figures from the NUPL that showed that 34 lawyers had been killed in the past two years. —WITH REPORTS FROM JULIE M. AURELIO AND DJ YAPRead Next

and

> Manila, Philippines—President .... but justice will eventually push its way through their walls of impunity, ... —REPORTS FROM MELVIN GASCON, JULIE M. AURELIO, DELFIN T. MALLARI JR., JEROME ANING, JOVIC YEE, GABRIEL PABICO LALU, PATHRICIA ANN V. ROXAS, DJ YAP, AFP, APRead Next

I want to remove the following phrases:

> "CEBU CITY—"
>
> "—WITH REPORTS FROM JULIE M. AURELIO AND DJ YAPRead Next"
>
> "Manila, Philippines—"
>
> "—REPORTS FROM MELVIN GASCON, JULIE M. AURELIO, DELFIN T. MALLARI JR., JEROME ANING, JOVIC YEE, GABRIEL PABICO LALU, PATHRICIA ANN V. ROXAS, DJ YAP, AFP, APRead Next"

I am assuming this would be needing two regex for each patterns enumerated above.

The regex: `—[A-Z].*Read Next\s*$` may work on the pattern # 2 but only when there are no other em dashes in the text data. It will not work when pattern # 1 occurs as it will remove the chunk from the first em dash it has seen until the "*Read Next*" string.

I have tried the following  regex for pattern # 1:

```
^[A-Z]([A-Za-z]).+(—)$
```

But how come it does not work. That regex was supposed to look for a phrase that starts with any upper case letter, followed by any length of string as long as it ends with an "—".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex that should take care of this -

```
^—[A-Z]+(.)*(Read Next)$
```

You can try implementing this regex on your data and see if it works out.

Answer (score 2):

What you are considering a hyphen `-` is not indeed a hyphen instead called [Em Dash](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/8212), hence you need to use this regex which has em dash instead of hyphen in start,

```
^—[A-Z].*Read Next\s*$
```

Here is the explanation for this regex,

- `^` --> Start of input
- `—` --> Matches a literal `Em Dash` whose Unicode Decimal Code is 8212
- `[A-Z]` --> Matches an upper case letter
- `.*` --> Matches any character zero or more times
- `Read Next` --> Matches these literal words
- `\s*` --> This is for matching any optional white space that might be present at the end of line
- `$` --> End of input

**[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/c665ue/1)**

Comment: This works! Thank you! btw, in the regex you provided, ",*" is the wild card for all the strings in between "—[A-Z]" and "Read Next" right? thanks again

Comment: Yes, Actually it is dot star `.*` which looks like by mistake you have written as `,*`. Let me add explanation of my regex to make it clear for anyone who reads it.

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh! I think the reason why it is not working on my data is because the regex is expecting the row to start with the EM Dash. The phrases that I want to omit are embedded inside a text. I have rephrased the question. TIA

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck: Ok, in that case, just remove `^` from the start of regex and then it will start matching anywhere in the line starting with em dash and will remove the content starting from emdash to end of line. Let me know if this works fine for you.

Comment: Thank you Pushpesh but after plugging that into my python code, it matched the whole data and removed it altogether.

Comment: Ok, if you don't want it to match whole data, then you should use non-greedy version of this regex. `—[A-Z].*?Read Next\s*$`

Comment: Apologies. it works but just found out now that apart from the pattern phrase I want to omit, there are other Em dashes "—" in the text data causing the code to omit a chunk of data from there. Now I need to find a way for the regex to ignore all other Em dashes in the data.

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck: No issues dear. I will help you solve any issue you are facing. Can you edit your post and provide more sample data and let me know how you want to transform your data?